# Getting the full HTTP Accept header string in restlet?

Tags: java, restlet-2.0

Apologies for the newbie question, but I am struggling a way to get the full contents of the HTTP Accept header received from the client web browser out of restlet (v 2.3.5) ?

This :

```
this.request.getHeaders().getFirstValue("Accept",true);
```

Does not work, I only get */* back.

I have also tried :

```
        List<Preference<MediaType>> mediaTypes = this.request.getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes();
    this.logger.debug(mediaTypes.toString());
    for (Iterator it = mediaTypes.iterator();it.hasNext();) {
        Preference<MediaType> preference = (Preference<MediaType>) it.next();
        this.logger.debug(preference.toString());
    }
```

Again, this only returns [*/*:1.0]  and */*:1.0 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact Restlet provides an object representation of elements present in the request. Regarding the `Accept` header, you have the following rules based on the `MediaType` class :

- the first element of the media type corresponds to the value of the media type (for example: `application/json`, ...)
- the second one to the quality
  value

If you want to know the corresponding value of the header would be:

```
Accept: media-type-value;q=quality,media-type-value;q=quality,media-type-value;q=quality
```

For example, if you get the following values using the code `getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes().toString()`:

```
[text/html:1.0, application/xhtml+xml:1.0, application/xml:0.9, image/webp:1.0, */*:0.8]
```

The corresponding header would be:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry